# How to dynamically change the xml node?

Tags: xml, go

I am using golang to  change the xml node dynamically? some struct is as the following:

```
type Row struct {
XMLName xml.Name `xml:"row"`
R string `xml:"r,attr,omitempty"`
}
```

after xml.Marshal(), it output maybe `"<row r="123"></row>"`
but i want to change the `"<row></row>"` to `"<myrow></myrow>"` if some condition is true.

how to dynamically change the xml node using golang?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's a working example: [Playground](http://play.golang.org/p/XNvXeU_H2D)

xml.Name has a field `Local` that contains the name for the tag.

If you set the value of `Local` to `"myrow"` it will output the struct as `<myrow r="..."></myrow>`.

Also, you have to remove the xml tag from the `XMLName` field. When the xml packages sees this tag (`xml:"row"`) it will automatically name the tag `"row"`, no matter what `XMLName` contains.

Answer (score 1):

If you remove the annotation on the `XMLName` field of the struct, then you can change its value to adjust how the struct will be marshalled.  For instance:

```
r.XMLName = xml.Name{"", "myrow"}
```

Would set the element name to `myrow` with an empty namespace.  The annotation needs to be removed because it will take precedence over the value of `XMLName`.

You can see the results of this here: http://play.golang.org/p/3hGbE5WO8D